# SQL Server 2008 Express Grant User Permission

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-express

What is the appropriate SQL commands (not through the GUI) to add a windows user account to permissions on a SQL Server 2008 Database?  ie.. I want to give someone read access and another person read/write..

Answer (score 17):

It's a two-step process:

- first, you need to create a **login** for that user, based on its Windows credentials

  ```
  CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<loginName>] FROM WINDOWS
  ```

  This sets up the basic permission to even connect to your SQL Server
- once you have a login, you can create a **user** in each database where you want to give that login rights to do something:

  ```
  CREATE USER Johnnie FOR LOGIN Domain\Johnnie;
  ```
- to grant read permissions on every table in your database, assign the `db_datareader` role to that user

  ```
  sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datareader', @membername = 'Johnnie'
  ```
- to grant read and write permissions on every table in your database, assign both the `db_datareader` as well as the `db_datawriter` role to that user
- if you need more fine grained control over what tables can be read from or written to, you need to manage permissions manually, e.g. by creating your own database roles and assigning grants to those roles, and then adding your users to those app-specific roles you created

Comment: Also, be sure you've enabled TCP/IP connections in the SQL Server Configuration Manager Tool. This is generally only an issue when you're trying to allow remote connections to your local machine. (Got bit by that earlier today. <g>)

Comment: Hello, i allow remote connections to my local machine. I created user and role but user has to see Sql Server Agent and job activity. What sould i do define role for the creating job.