# How come EF 4.1 cannot create a database when logged in as a domain user?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584546/ef-4-1-cf-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master) before, but this one is specific to Development, not migrating to production.

When logged in as a domain user on my Windows 7 computer, and starting up an EF 4.1 project, I get an error, because Entity Framework cannot create a database in 'dbo.master' in my local instances of SQL Express.

If I take the same project and run it as local admin on my Windows 7 laptop it works perfectly.

What do I need to do to my Windows 7 Desktop in order to grant EF 4.1 the rights to drop/create databases on my local instance of SQL Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your domain user to the `dbcreator` role on your local instance of SQL Express. Or if you want full rights, add yourself to `dbo` role.

See this SO answer: [SQL Server 2008 Express Grant User Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725966/sql-server-2008-express-grant-user-permission)

Or you could add your Domain User account to the machines local admin account. But that has wider implications (obviously).

Comment: That was the right concept and a good pointer, still working through the details so I can update this question with the specifics.